# SQL Server Reporting Services 2005; subscriptions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, subscriptions

I have an issue with the comments in subscriptions in report manager.

No matter what format I create the comment in, format is lost when the report is mailed out and the paragraphs in the comment are removed, leaving just sentences. Since our reporting is new to users, I need to include some instructions and they require paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML tag `<br/>`.

```
this is line one. <br/> this is second line. <br/><br/> add two blank spaces.
```

Answer (score 0):

Following some tests, I don't think this is possible.

I just tried creating a data-driven subscription using a stored procedure, and set the comment to use a value from my stored procedure results.  I hard coded this value as:

`'abc' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'def'`

If you `select` this expression in SSMS *with results to text*, you'll see it displays over multiple lines.  However, in the email it was still on one line!

**Edit** Check out [this article](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/363358/reporting-services-subscription-email-body-line-breaks-removed) on MS Connect.  It looks like it was fixed in 2008 R2 which isn't much use to you.  However there is a suggested workaround which is to use HTML markup such as `<br />` tags.  This to me seems ugly, but if you can be sure your recipients use HTML email then it might solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The emails are generated using HTML so if you use standard HTML tags such as `<br>` for line breaks etc your formatting will be preserved in the email.